# Exit Method then re enter (at the same point)? JAVA

Tags: java

Is there anyway to exit a method and then re-enter that method at the exact point from another class?

For example:
Class 1:

```
Keypresser.KeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
wpressed = true
KeyPresser.KeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
```

Class 2:

```
while(Class1.wpressed == true){
CANCEL CLASS 1 AT CURRENT STANDING
thread.wait(1);
RESUMS CLASS 1 AT THAT STANDING
}
```

Comment: Hypothetically yes, however if you feel you need to do something like this "you're doing it wrong".

Answer (score 1):

No, Java provides no way for programmers to re-enter a method at an arbitrary point in code. Although the method could be pre-empted by the scheduler to let other threads run, and then resumed from the same point, there is no mechanism available to Java programmers to do the same.

You need to build a communication mechanism to pass information between your threads. For example, you can use a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) object to signal a thread when to stop and when to continue. Of course the running thread must be executing your code at the time when you tell it to pause itself.